# How to get component object in richtext without using strong type [Kontent Delivery SDK .NET]

Tags: .net, sdk, components, richtext, kentico-kontent

As Title, I can't find how to get a component object in richtext without using a strong type.

```
DeliveryItemListingResponse listingResponse = await kentontClient.GetItemsAsync(
     new InFilter("system.type", "property")
);

foreach(var item in listingResponse.Items)
{
     var spec = item.GetLinkedItems("d3cb9f23_7684_0174_0b8d_6320bb61cc62");
}
```

It throws an exception. The component `d3cb9f23_7684_0174_0b8d_6320bb61cc62` object exists in a private member `_linkedItemsSource`. 
I'm guessing that `GetLinkedItems` searches just under its elements only.

Are there any way we can get it?

Ref:
https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-delivery-sdk-net/wiki/String-based-rendering-of-items-in-Rich-text

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely.

The `GetLinkedItems` expects the codename of the element which contains linked items. -> Not the codename of a specific linked item. (Though, such method would probably be handy. You can request it by submitting an issue in the repo: https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-delivery-sdk-net/issues)

What you want to do is:

```
var linkeditems = item.GetLinkedItems("element_codename");
var yourDesiredLinkedItem = linkeditems.Where(i => i.System.Codename == "d3cb9f23_7684_0174_0b8d_6320bb61cc62");
```